# Optics - focusing Sun's rays

Tags: thermodynamics, optics

If I have a ten centimeter diameter convergent lens, and I use it to focus the sun's rays onto a surface, is there a maximum temperature I could get this surface? I know it can't be higher than the temperature of the surface of the sun because of thermodynamics, but I was wondering if the diameter of the lens also affected the maximum temperature.

Comment: Duplicate - [Take your pick](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=APq-WBth0IJbZcrZwu6ZjE4XibXBhqOUAQ:1645345541017&q=maximum+temperature+focussing+sun%27s+rays+physics+stack+exchange&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKwYTk7Y32AhXKT8AKHWTeDRkQBSgAegQIARAy&biw=1548&bih=906&dpr=1.2) as to the number of reference to this sort of question on Physics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diameter of the lens does not limit the temperature in a fundamental way. If, for example, the lens focused the sun onto a perfectly insulated surface (that is, the only way for it to lose energy is by radiation back out through the lens), then the surface would reach the temperature of the sun. Even if the lens was extremely low-powered (small-diameter, say, or low curvature), and the light flux small, eventually the temperature would get there because the heat has nowhere else to go.

Of course, in the real world, a tighter focus with a larger numerical aperture will increase the temperature because the radiative heating is competing with parasitic thermal conductive channels. So higher flux makes things hotter. But the better the insulation, the less this matters.

Comment: +1 I’ve heard it said that the larger/more elaborate/more comprehensive the lens/mirror system, the more it seems like the Sun is effectively surrounding the target. (This, of course, emphasizes the inability to exceed the Sun’s temperature through passive optics.) This reasoning is consistent with your analysis, I believe.